# Fabric.js - Sync object:modified event to another client

Tags: events, canvas, socket.io, synchronization, fabricjs

Collaboration Mode:

What is the best way to propagate changes from Client #1's canvas to client #2's canvas? Here's how I capture and send events to Socket.io.

```
$scope.canvas.on('object:modified',function(e) { 
  Socket.whiteboardMessage({
    eventId:'object:modified',
    event:e.target.toJSON()
  });
});
```

On the receiver side, this code works splendidly for adding **new** objects to the screen, but I could not find documentation on how to **select** and **update** an existing object in the canvas.

```
fabric.util.enlivenObjects([e.event], function(objects) {
  objects.forEach(function(o) {
    $scope.canvas.add(o);
  });
});
```

I did see that Objects have individual setters and one bulk setter, but I could not figure out how to select an existing object based on the event data.

Ideally, the flow would be:

1. Receive event with targeted object data.
2. Select the existing object in the canvas.
3. Perform bulk update.
4. Refresh canvas.

Hopefully someone with Fabric.JS experience can help me figure this out.  Thanks!

**UPDATED ANSWER - Thanks AJM!**

AJM was correct in suggesting a unique ID for every newly created element. I was also able to create a new ID for all newly created drawing paths as well. Here's how it worked:

```
var t = new fabric.IText('Edit me...', { 
  left: $scope.width/2-100, 
  top: $scope.height/2-50 
});
t.set('id',randomHash());
$scope.canvas.add(t);
```

I also captured newly created paths and added an id:

```
$scope.canvas.on('path:created',function(e) {
  if (e.target.id === undefined) {
    e.target.set('id',randomHash());
  }
});
```

However, I encountered an issue where my ID was visible in console log, but it was not present after executing `object.toJSON()`. This is because Fabric has its own serialization method which trims down the data to a standardized list of properties. To include additional properties, I had to serialize the data for transport like so:

```
$scope.canvas.on('object:modified',function(e) { 
  Socket.whiteboardMessage({
    object:e.target.toJSON(['id']) // includes "id" in output.
  })
});
```

Now each object has a unique ID with which to perform updates. On the receiver's side of my code, I added AJM's object-lookup function. I placed this code in the "startup" section of my application so it would only run once (after Fabric.js is loaded, of course!)

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.getObjectById = function (id) {
    var objs = this.getObjects();
    for (var i = 0, len = objs.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (objs[i].id == id) {
            return objs[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Now, whenever a new socket.io message is received with whiteboard data, I am able to find it in the canvas via this line:

```
var obj = $scope.canvas.getObjectById(e.object.id);
```

Inserting and removing are easy, but for updating, this final piece of code did the trick:

```
obj.set(e.object); // Updates properties
$scope.canvas.renderAll(); // Redraws canvas
$scope.canvas.calcOffset(); // Updates offsets
```

All of this required me to handle the following events. Paths are treated as objects once they're created.

```
$scope.canvas.on('object:added',function(e) { });
$scope.canvas.on('object:modified',function(e) { });
$scope.canvas.on('object:moving',function(e) { });
$scope.canvas.on('object:removed',function(e) { });
$scope.canvas.on('path:created',function(e) { });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar involving a single shared canvas between multiple users and ran into this exact issue.

To solve this problem, I added unique IDs (using a javascript UUID generator) to each object added to the canvas (in my case, there could be many users working on a canvas at a time, thus I needed to avoid collisions; in your case, something simpler could work).

Fabric objects' `set` method will let you add an arbitrary property, like an id: `o.set('id', yourid)`. Before you `add()` a new Fabric object to your canvas (and send that across the wire), tack on an ID property. Now, you'll have a unique key by which you can pick out individual objects.

From there, you'd need a method to retrieve an object by ID. Here's what I used:

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.getObjectById = function (id) {
    var objs = this.getObjects();
    for (var i = 0, len = objs.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (objs[i].id == id) {
            return objs[i];
        }
    }

    return null;
};
```

When you receive data from your socket, grab that object from the canvas by ID and mutate it using the appropriate `set` methods or copying properties wholesale (or, if `getObjectById` returns `null`, create it).

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the tip. How did you solve adding id's to paths generated in free-draw mode? It sounds like you used path:added and assigned an ID to it if it did not already have one... is that correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, we didn't need to support free drawing in our application, so I can't answer that one (I docked a "palette" at the side of our app that contained shapes, arrows, images, and a few text objects that I created; I can vouch for basically everything except free drawing paths). Hazarding a guess, but as long as paths have a unique ID property (that is there or that you set), everything *should* work the same (you'd be able to select them by ID and then apply the appropriate mutations).

Comment: The drawing worked exactly like the objects, except I had to listen for path:created in order to set an ID.  I updated my answer with the full set of codes.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for editing your question and adding that; I'm sure someone else will find it very useful.